# JS Select dynamic id by pattern

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to select a dynamic ID. I have a page where I have a block with the id pattern `<div id="post-id-{1,2,3,...}">...</div>`. Since there is a different ID for each post in the detail view, I can't tell in advance which ID it will be. Nevertheless I want to select the block. Can I do something like passing a regex like `\poll-id-(id)\` to querySelector? Or do I have to store the post ID somewhere to build my querySelector string from it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use startsWith [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors):

```
document.querySelector("[id^='post-id']")
```

contains

```
document.querySelector("[id*='post-id']")
```

or the whole thing, but then you need to [escape](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS/escape) the curlies and other characters the selector does not like

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector

```js
const id = CSS.escape(`post-id-{1,2,3,4}`)
console.log(id,document.querySelector(`[id=${id}]`).textContent)
```

```html
<div id="post-id-{1,2,3,4}">Div with nasty ID</div>
```